# How to get missing summary data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that gives me total sales by Month.  However, there are some months where there are no sales.  How did I get a 0 value for that Month in my query results?

```
SELECT
    p.Part,
    SUM(s.Sales) AS Sales,
    MONTH(s.SalesDate) AS Month_Sold
FROM
    Parts p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales s ON p.Part = s.Part
GROUP BY
    p.Part,
    MONTH(s.SalesDate)
ORDER BY
    p.Part,
    Month_Sold
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `SUM(ISNULL(s.Sales, 0))` so that your NULL values aren't eliminated by the aggregate. Although, since you're depending on your month from your sales data as well, you're going to need to have a Month look up so that you can see all the months even if you don't have them in your sales data.

So, something like this:

```
    ;WITH months AS
    (
        SELECT 1 AS mo
        UNION ALL
        SELECT mo +1
        FROM months
        WHERE mo < 12
    )

    SELECT p.Part, SUM(s.Sales) AS Sales, mo AS Month_Sold 
    FROM Parts p 
    CROSS APPLY months
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales s 
        ON p.Part = s.Part 
        AND months.mo = MONTH(s.SalesDate) 
    GROUP BY p.Part, months.mo ORDER BY p.Part, Month_Sold
```

Comment: It's worth noting that MONTH() by itself can be inaccurate if you're not also grouping or filtering by year.

Comment: Yes, I just looked at that.  Year will need to be added in as well.  How can that be accomplished?

Comment: @user2174734 So if you just wanted per one year, you could add a @Year parameter, add that as a column on the months CTE and filter Sales. Otherwise, you'd want to have another CTE below months that did something similar with a years column. `years as(SELECT 2010 as yr, mo from months union all select yr + 1, mo from years where yr < 2014)`